# Is the value of the expression correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

We have the matrix $C=\begin{pmatrix}z& -w\\ \overline{w}&\overline{z}\end{pmatrix}$ with $z,w\in \mathbb{C}$.

I want to have a property for $z,w$ so that $C$ is unitary.

Suppose that $z=\frac{-2+4i}{11}$ and $w=\frac{1-10i}{t}$, where $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

If $C$ is unitary I want to calculate $x=11|t|$ and then the value of the expression $x^3-4x^2-5x+23$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

So that $C$ is unitary it must hold that $C^*=C^{-1}$, where $C^*$ is the complex transpose of $C$.

We have that $C^*=\begin{pmatrix}\overline{z}& w\\ -\overline{w}&z\end{pmatrix}$ and $C^{-1}=\frac{1}{|z|^2+|w|^2}\begin{pmatrix}\overline{z}& w\\ -\overline{w}&z\end{pmatrix}$.

Therefore we get $$C^*=C^{-1}\Rightarrow |z|^2+|w|^2=1 \Rightarrow \frac{20}{121}+\frac{101}{t^2}=1 \Rightarrow \frac{101}{t^2}=\frac{101}{121} \Rightarrow t^2=121\Rightarrow |t|=11$$

So, $x=11\cdot 11=121$.

Therefore the value of the expression becomes $$x^3-4x^2-5x+23=121^3-4\cdot 121^2-5\cdot 121+23=1712415$$ 
Is everything correct?

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: Ok, thank you!! :-) @user1551